# Detecting AJAX request with $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] only works the first time?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I have a conditional statement to determine if a request is AJAX or not:

```
if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
// AJAX specific code
} else {
// GET specific code
}
```

It works. Kind of. As soon as I make an AJAX request, the server continues to think every request for the following minute or two is an AJAX request.

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax method to access the page.

You can see the error at work on a live site. If you visit http://benjaminallison.com/ and click the first link (for Burger Derby) the info loads as intended.

If you go to the direct link (http://benjaminallison.com/projects/burger-derby/), it also works as intended. However, if you click the link on the page, triggering the AJAX call then try the direct link, or simply try to visit the direct link again, you'll be presented with a page generated by the AJAX specific code!

I have no idea if this is a browser/header issue, a jQuery issue, or a server issue.

The weird thing is I've used this same technique on other sites and it's worked fine; perhaps it's host (MediaTemple) specific.

Comment: The code looks fine, i would suspect a server response caching issue. Try printing the date/time, does it change with each request?

Comment: That's my suspicion. I know very little about server configuration. Where could I do some reading on that?

Comment: That depends on what webserver you are using. Before you start researching though, do the simple test i added to my first comment, if you get a different time with each request, it's not caching.

Comment: I echo'd the date and it changes with a page refresh, so I guess it's not caching.

Comment: Weird... I'm trying `if ( strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"], 'json') !== false)` and it's working. For some reason the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` isn't being released or something...

Comment: You aren't using any history.pushState magic are you?

Comment: Mmmmmmaybe *hides face*. Yeah I am. How did you know!?

Comment: because that typically involves requesting pages with ajax, which your php script would pick up as... ajax. :)

Comment: Oh, I am using pushState, but where/how I'm using it and, where I'm detecting if a request is AJAX, it shouldn't have any bearing. I'm not experiencing the issue on my local development server, and didn't experience it on a similarly functioning site hosted elsewhere...